# Late 1980s horizontal and vertical scrolling plane shooter coin-op arcade game

Tags: identify-this-game, coin-op

It was a coin-op, late 80s, probably JAMA cabinet, which featured both horizontal and vertical scrolling fighter-plane shooter actions, with upgradeable weapons.  Later than Slap Fight, with grubbier graphics..  Bombs could be dropped, in vertical scrolling over the landscape, and it was possible to fly into the bomb crater to switch to horizontal scrolling.

Any clues as to the name?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't see that an arcade game, with which you had no involvement except to play it, has anything to do with this site, which is about retrocomputing.

Comment: I am not too happy about the flood of video game ID questions either, but saying it has nothing to do with retrocomputing seems more like an application of the hammer principle (I want this question closed, the only way it will be closed is if it’s off-topic, therefore it must be off-topic) than an honest justification. If you don’t like this post because it’s a lazy game ID question, just say so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are thinking of ***Terra Force*** (1987) by Nihon Bussan.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!